# Eliminate/Remove duplicates from array Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I remove any number that has duplicate from an array.

for example:

```
b =[ 1 1 2 3 3 5 6]
```

becomes

```
b =[ 2 5 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `unique` function to extract unique values then compute histogram of data for unique values and preserve those that have counts of 1.

```
a =[ 1 1 2 3 3 5 6];
u = unique(a)
idx = hist(a, u) ==1;
b = u(idx)
```

result

```
  2 5 6
```

for multi column input this can be done:

```
a = [1 2; 1 2;1 3;2 1; 1 3; 3 5 ; 3 6; 5 9; 6 10] ;
[u ,~, uid] = unique(a,'rows');
idx = hist(uid,1:size(u,1))==1;
b= u(idx,:)
```

Comment: Thanks rahnema1, how about if I have two or more columns?                    A = [1 2; 1 2;1 3;2 1; 1 3; 3 5 ; 3 6;  5 9; 6 10] A =

     1     2
     1     2
     1     3
     2     1
     1     3
     3     5
     3     6
     5     9
     6    10
the result should be like:                                                                                       2     1
3     5
3     6
5     9
6    10

Comment: If `a` is in random order and the same order is to be preserved, we are out of luck here since it gives the sorted answer. :(

Comment: @SardarUsama OK,You are right. You may post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I haven't thought of  a solution yet. I found your answer while searching for a dupe target for [***this question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528939/totally-remove-elements-that-appear-multiple-times-in-array-matlab?noredirect=1&lq=1). One of the answers there are valid for the problem I described.)

Comment: @Thanks! Good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort your elements and afterwards remove all elements which have the same value as one of its neighbors as follows:

```
A_sorted = sort(A); % sort elements
A_diff = diff(A_sorted)~=0; % check if element is the different from the next one 
A_unique = [A_diff true] & [true A_diff]; % check if element is different from previous and next one
A = A_sorted(A_unique); % obtain the unique elements.
```

**Benchmark**

I will benchmark my solution with the other provided solutions, i.e.:

- using `diff` (my solution)
- [using `hist`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40393541/7621674) (rahnema1)
- [using `sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46529311/7621674) (Jean Logeart)
- using `unique` (my alternative solution)

I will use two cases:

- small problem (yours): `A = [1 1 2 3 3 5 6];`
- larger problem

  ```
  rng('default');
  A= round(rand(1, 1000) * 300);
  ```

---

*Result:*

```
                  Small        Large       Comments
----------------|------------|------------%----------------
 using `diff`   | 6.4080e-06 | 6.2228e-05 % Fastest method for large problems
 using `unique` | 6.1228e-05 | 2.1923e-04 % Good performance
 using `sum`    | 5.4352e-06 | 0.0020     % Only fast for small problems, preserves the original order
 using `hist`   | 8.4408e-05 | 1.5691e-04 % Good performance
```

My solution (using `diff`) is the fastest method for somewhat larger problems. The solution of Jean Logeart using `sum` is faster for small problems, but the slowest method for larger problems, while mine is almost equally fast for the small problem.

**Conclusion:** In general, my proposed solution using `diff` is the fastest method.

---

```
timeit(@() usingDiff(A))
timeit(@() usingUnique(A))
timeit(@() usingSum(A))
timeit(@() usingHist(A))

function A = usingDiff (A)
    A_sorted = sort(A);
    A_unique = [diff(A_sorted)~=0 true] & [true diff(A_sorted)~=0];
    A = A_sorted(A_unique);
end

function A = usingUnique (A)
    [~, ia1] = unique(A, 'first');
    [~, ia2] = unique(A, 'last');
    A = A(ia1(ia1 == ia2));
end

function A = usingSum (A)
    A = A(sum(A==A') == 1);
end

function A = usingHist (A)
    u = unique(A);
    A = u(hist(A, u) ==1);
end
```