# Totally remove elements that appear multiple times in array Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given the following array:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,2,4,5,8,4,6,7,1,2,8,5,14,100,101];
```

how can every elements that appear multiple times be removed in the simplest manner, without any computational effort, for any general case i.e, to obtain:

```
A=[3,9,14,100,101];
```

Comment: I added a [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531458/7621674) to compare the different methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
res = A(sum(A==A') == 1)  % keep elements whose frequency is exactly 1
> res =
 3     9    14   100   101
```

Since `sum(A==A')` returns the frequency of each element.

Comment: `'` is not transpose. It is complex conjugate transpose. `.'` is transpose

Comment: This method is only valid for MATLAB R2016b or later, I have added an alternative answer using `bsxfun` suitable for all versions, following this methodology.

Comment: Note that this approach is really slow for large problems, but it indeed preserves the original order. See [my benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393513/eliminate-remove-duplicates-from-array-matlab/46531458#46531458) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort your elements and afterwards remove all elements which have the same value as one of its neighbors as follows:

```
A_sorted = sort(A); % sort elements
A_diff = diff(A_sorted)~=0; % check if element is the different from the next one 
A_unique = [A_diff true] & [true A_diff]; % check if element is different from previous and next one
A = A_sorted(A_unique); % obtain the unique elements.
```

Comment: The elements at the end will also be sorted with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In versions earlier than 2016b (before [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) became a thing) you can use `bsxfun` to imitate [Jean's result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46529311/3978545) which uses implicit expansion:

```
out = A(sum(bsxfun(@(x,y) x==y, A, A.'))==1)

>> out = [3 9 14 100 101]
```