# Deleting non-unique rows from an array

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates, unique, rows

I have an array `a` as follows:

```
a = [ 1 2; 3 4; 1 2 ];
```

I want to delete all rows appearing more than once in `a` and get `c`:

```
c = [ 3 4 ];
```

Please note that this is not the same operation as keeping unique rows, since I don't want rows that had duplicates to appear at all. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminate/Remove duplicates from array Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393513/eliminate-remove-duplicates-from-array-matlab)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The third output of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) gives you the index of the unique row in the original array. You can use this with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to count the number of occurrences, which can be used to select rows that occur only once.

For example:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 1 2];

[uniquerow, ~, rowidx] = unique(A, 'rows'); 
noccurrences = accumarray(rowidx, 1);

C = uniquerow(noccurrences==1, :);
```

Which returns:

```
>> C

C =

     3     4
```