# How to find the repeated values in a matrix and which rows they belong to?

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates

I have a m-by-1 matrix, `A`. I want to find out which elements are duplicates and get their row values. (Just the row values because the matrix is m-by-1.)

I've tried

```
k = find(~unique(A));
```

but k contains the wrong values.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Consider the array A;

```
A = [4
     5
     5
     5
     7
     8
     4];
```

Since 4 and 5 are the repeated elements here, I would like to get the row values of these elements and put them in a new array. The resulting array would be

```
RowValues= [1
            2
            3
            4
            7];
```

Note: The above is just an example and the actual array I am dealing with contains rational numbers of the type -0.0038, 1.3438 and so on in the array `A`.

Comment: When you try `unique(A)`, think (or read the doc) what `~` would do to it

Comment: Related [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393513/eliminate-remove-duplicates-from-array-matlab) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645621/deleting-non-unique-rows-from-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`intersect`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
s = sort(A);
c = intersect(s(1:2:end),s(2:2:end));
RowValues = find(ismember(A,c));
```

I have [compared](http://rextester.com/EXLJM47941) this method with the method proposed by @SardarUsama with a large `[1 x 10000000]` input in Octave. Here is the result:

```
=======INTERSECT==========
Elapsed time is 1.94979 seconds.

=======ACCUMARRAY==========
Elapsed time is 2.5205 seconds.
```

Comment: It took me some time to understand the input arguments of intersect. That's clever, I must say.

Comment: I've run this code as it is but it's skipping over some elements in the array. I should have mentioned this but does this code work for positive and negative fractional numbers as well? I'm sorry, I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: Its result is the same as the method provided by other answer. You can compare them [online](http://rextester.com/EXLJM47941)

Comment: @Matte The elements in your array that you consider same are not *really* same. Read [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab) and [***this***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for the insight.

Comment: @Sardar Usama Yes, I'd only been seeing a part of the number. I rounded off the digits and now I'm getting the right answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Find the count of each element of `A` using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), filter out the non-repeating values, use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to get the logical indices of repeating values and then use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to convert them to linear indices.

```
[C, ~, ic] = unique(A);    
RowValues = find(ismember(A, C(accumarray(ic,1)>1)));
```

---

***Why you get the wrong indices with your code?***
Applying [logical NOT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) on the vector of unique values would convert them to a logical vector containing [`true`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/true.html) at the index where unique value is zero and [`false`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/false.html) where it is non-zero and hence finding the non-zero (`false` in this case) elements of such a vector would lead nowhere.